# Dynamic Tooltips: TTN_GETDISPINFO not send when using LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, tooltip

I am trying to add dynamic tooltips to my mfc application. I am able to display tooltips using `CToolTipCtrl` with static text. But when I change the text to `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` I don't get a `TTN_GETDISPINFO` notification to set the text and nothing gets displayed anymore.

I created a new MFC project from scratch and there it works. So something must be different in my application. But I am not able to find out, what I do wrong or where I should start looking.

What could be possible reasons for this behaviour? Is it possible that the notifications diverted to somewhere else?

I added the handler like this:

```
ON_NOTIFY(TTN_GETDISPINFO, NULL, OnToolTipNotify)

void CChildView::OnToolTipNotify(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    TOOLTIPTEXTW* pTTTW = (TOOLTIPTEXTW*)pNMHDR;
    wsprintf(pTTTW->szText,L"Hello World!");
}
```

The tooltip was added in the `OnCreate` function using the `CMyToolTipCtrl` class from Jeff Prosise MFC book:

```
CToolTipCtrl* tooltip = new CToolTipCtrl;
tooltip->Create(this, TTS_ALWAYSTIP);
TOOLINFO ti;
ti.cbSize = sizeof (TOOLINFO);
ti.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
ti.hwnd = this->GetSafeHwnd ();
ti.uId = (UINT) tooltip->GetSafeHwnd ();
ti.hinst = AfxGetInstanceHandle ();
ti.lpszText = (LPTSTR) LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK;

SendMessage (TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) &ti);
```

If I change the second to last line to

```
ti.lpszText = (LPTSTR) L"Hello World!";
```

the tooltip gets displayed in my application, too.

Comment: [TTN_GETDISPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760269.aspx): *"This notification code is sent in the form of a [**WM_NOTIFY**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx) message."* Have you installed a `WM_NOTIFY` message handler in the owner window? Please show your code.

Comment: As I said, it works on a newly created project. But I will add the code.

Comment: `this` can be anything. Is `CChildView` the owner window of `CMyToolTipCtrl`?

Comment: This code gets executed in `CChildView::OnCreate`. So `this` refers to the `CChildView` instance. Here is the code of the whole `CChildView` class of the working sample application I created: http://pastebin.com/FLYaRAwu .

Comment: Have you tried replacing `CMyToolTipCtrl` with a stock [`CToolTipCtrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b4cb3a5.aspx), to verify that the custom control implementation is not causing this.

Comment: It is a very simple control. (It is included in the pastebin). Basically just one function that takes care of adding the Tooltip to the control. I just tried using that code directly without the custom control. No change in behaviour.

Comment: In that case I wouldn't know the answer either. I'd still recommend replacing the custom control with the standard Tooltip control in the question. That way the question (and answer) will be valuable to a larger audience, and both will be show up in a `CToolTipCtrl` search.

Comment: Thank you for the hint and I appreciate your effort.

Comment: With the updated code, I can see two potential issues: `1` The *uId* member should be the handle to the **tool** window (i.e. the window for which the tooltip control will be displayed). In your original code, this was the `CChildView` window. `2` The *TTF_SUBCLASS* flag intercepts messages. Although the messages aren't explicitly listed, you could try removing that flag. You could also replace the entire code adding a tool window with a call to `tooltip->AddTool(this);`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem of your project setting.

What kind of project is it? Unicode or MBCS.

If it is an MBCS message you might miss the notification because the tooltip is an unicode window and sends TTN_GETDISPINFOW!
So best practice for me is to implement always both notifications TTN_GETDISPINFOW and TTN_GETDISPINFOA.

You might check this with Spy++